# Limit Decimal Places In Generated Numbers in R.Studio

Tags: decimal

I am a beginner in programmin in general and R specifically.

I would like to generate a set of random numbers in a normal distribution but to limit the decimal places in these numbers to only 2.

I have been using x1 <- runif() to generate my numbers.

Can I add something to it to enable me to only get results rounded off to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the decimal places using the round() function.

If I understand your question correctly this should do the trick:

```
x1 <- round(
  runif(5, min=0, max=1)   
  , digits = 2
)
x1
```

The results, which will be different each time, are:

```
[1] 0.55 0.55 0.75 0.85 0.13
```